# Why aren't my tab contents changing on click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have three tabs that should be changing when clicked on, and I don't know why they aren't changing.

```
function activeTab(tab) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
activeTab('searchtab1');
```

Link to my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/s1f9Lqzn/

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: no I have not checked. I was trying to copy this example http://jsfiddle.net/pThn6/333/ but it doesn't work

Comment: From your fiddle, I would say one big problem is you aren't including any javascript that handles "tab" as a function

Comment: @midnight the example that you are referring to utilizes jquery and bootstrap. Are you including jquery and bootstrap in your code?

Comment: I updated it to put them in the <li> tags https://jsfiddle.net/m3y52t04/

Comment: For what it's worth, I've posted a solution to a different question that solves your problem with essentially just CSS:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55448495/362536  You might find that example and JSFiddle useful.

Comment: @midnight check this out - https://jsfiddle.net/dpollard/5oawem6v/23/

Comment: exactly what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your fiddle add jquery and jquery-ui and jquery-ui.css (for tabs) and add id="tabs" to the div that contains the ul li for tabls as under:

```
<div id="tabs" class="searcht">
```

and you just need to call

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

Please check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fcwjoh5k/):

Your CSS has some issues. I removed your css to use the css that comes with jquery-ui.css and it seems to be working well.

https://jsfiddle.net/htwryn4g/

Comment: @midnight - did this answer your question?